# winui 3 : why svg icon doesn't render correctly?

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-11

I'm building a `NavigationView` with static and dynamic `MenuItems`.
Each static menu item has an svg icon loaded from an uri.
Each dynamic menu item has an svg icon loaded from a stream source.

[Svg icon url](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Android_Jelly_Bean_Logo.svg)

xaml snippet of the static menu item

```
 <NavigationViewItem Content="Static item">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <ImageIcon Source="/Assets/Android_Jelly_Bean_Logo.svg"/>
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
```

c# snippet of the dynamics items

```
  private async void _addNavigationItem()
    {
        var svgCode = "<my svg code string>";

        var svgSource = new SvgImageSource();
        var imageIcon = new ImageIcon();
        imageIcon.Source = svgSource;
        var svgBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(svgCode, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

            using (var stream = svgBuffer.AsStream())
            {
               await svgSource.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
            }


     
        var item = new NavigationViewItem() {
            Content = "hello",
            Icon = imageIcon
        };

      
        NavigationViewControl.MenuItems.Add(item);
      
    }
```

[image]

Why the dynamic svg icons doesn't render correctly ?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me (or unexpected behavior) you should report to Microsoft. A workaround is to always use an UriSource and don't use SetSourceAsync, ie: `svgSource.UriSource = new Uri("some real path/uri to Android_Jelly_Bean_Logo.svg");` this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't notice that @Simon Mourier already gave you a workaround, but since I already created a project for this, let me show you a working sample code:

```cs
ImageIcon imageIcon = new()
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Android_Jelly_Bean_Logo.svg"))
};

NavigationViewItem navigationViewItem = new()
{
    Content = "Hello",
    Icon = imageIcon,
};

NavigationViewControl.MenuItems.Add(navigationViewItem);
```